# Returning column values by condition of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the planes data frame in the R package, nycflights13. I am trying to select the years that have all 3 types (fixed multi, fixed single, rotorcraft) that occur in the same year. I have tried creating a subset:

```
subset(planes$year, planes$type == "Fixed wing multi engine" & 
planes$type == "Fixed wing single engine" & planes$type == "Rotorcraft")
```

And multiple attempts with dplyr:

```
    planes %>% filter(type == "Fixed wing multi engine" & 
type == "Fixed wing single engine" & type == "Rotorcraft")%>% group_by(year)
```

This hasn't worked. How would I go about doing something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr route.  The key is (a) to `group_by()` year first, and (b) to use the `n_distinct()` function.

```
planes %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(n_distinct(type) == 3)
```

Note: this code implicitly assumes that the data has no other `type`s than "Fixed wing multi engine", "Fixed wing single engine", and "Rotorcraft".  This is true for the `planes` dataframe but might not always be.  It might be preferable to make this assumption explicit, but it would result in longer code.

```
planes %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
filter("Fixed wing multi engine" %in% type & 
       "Rotorcraft" %in% type & 
       "Fixed wing single engine" %in% type)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `subset` and `filter` operate on rows. So one row cannot contain all 3 types.

One approach is to group by year, then count the number of distinct types. Since you know in advance that there are 3 types, you can then filter for that count:

```
library(dplyr)

planes %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(type) == 3)
```

This returns 26 rows. You can use `count()` or `distinct()` to show that those years are 1975 and 1985.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put it out there, here's a base R solution using `ave()` -

```
n_types <- length(unique(planes$type))

unique(
  planes$year[ave(planes$type, planes$year, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == n_types]
)

[1] 1985 1975
```